# Docker run tomcat errors

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile, supervisord

I got some problem when i was trying to run this command

```
docker run -d -t -p 203:22 -p 7003:8080 -v /home/test/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/ --name tomcat3 tomcat
```

this command can be executed correctly，but the tomcat server in the docker would stopped like this：

```
07-Mar-2017 10:10:24.341 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/examples
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/examples has finished in 669 ms
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.069 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager has finished in 58 ms
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.069 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/docs
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.116 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/docs has finished in 47 ms
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.117 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.147 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 30 ms
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.159 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.171 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Mar-2017 10:10:25.171 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1757 ms
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.418 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.420 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.425 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.426 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.495 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.499 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.499 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Mar-2017 10:11:31.500 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

But that is not the case in the following command.

```
docker run -d -t -p 201:22 -p 7001:8080  --name tomcat1 tomcat
```

this command would execute exactly correct.The only different between them is the flag `-v` in my opinion.Here is my Dockerfile and supervisord config

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
[program:tomcat]
command=/usr/local/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh run
environment=JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk8/",JAVA_BIN="/usr/local/java/jdk8/bin"
autostart = true
autorestart=true
[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

#Dockerfile 
FROM tomcat
EXPOSE 22 8080
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: Check on the host if the ports 203 and 7003 are used

Comment: Both of them were free to use

Comment: Post ` lsof -i:203 -i :7003` on the host